# ImproperlyConfigured middleware in Django project (error importing redis function)

Tags: django, redis, middleware

I'm writing a middleware for a Django app of mine where I get a variable from `request.session` and then have to insert it into a redis sorted set. Fairly straight forward.

I.e.

```
import os
#os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","myproject.settings")
from myapp.redis_functions import set_whose_online

class WhoseOnlineMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if '_auth_user_id' in request.session:
            set_whose_online(request.session['_auth_user_id'])
        else:
            pass
```

`redis_functions.py` contains all redis related functions in my app. The redis connection pool is instantiated there as well.

But this is giving me an `ImporperlyConfigured` error at `import`. The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 83, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware myproject.middleware.WhoseOnline: "cannot import name add_filtered_post"
```

It's perplexing because I'm not trying to import `add_filtered_post`, I'm trying to import `set_whose_online`. `add_filtered_post` is another function in `redis_functions.py`, used entirely elsewhere.

What could be possibly going on, and how can I remedy this problem? I was guessing circular imports are to blame, but `python manage.py validate --traceback` returns 0 errors.

---

Here's what I have in my `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'myproject.middleware.XForwardedFor.XForwardedForMiddleware',
    'user_sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.WhoseOnline.WhoseOnlineMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.HellBanned.HellBannedMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'mobileesp.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

*Note: the middleware is added at `myfolder/myproject/middleware/WhoseOnline.py`, i.e the same folder as settings.py, urls, templates*

Comment: You certainly shouldn't be mucking around with DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in a middleware module, although that isn't the cause of your problem.

Comment: Middleware can only be used in the context of an existing project. Any project will already have its settings module defined; it doesn't make sense to change that environment variable within the middleware file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there could be various reasons for this to happen, in my particular case it was because of **circular imports**. I diagnosed and solved the problem, and this went away.